# Train Setup in The Place That Lies Beyond

Tags: stuffed-fables

I have re-read the entire rules and first pages of the story book, and either I am missing something, or the game is not entirely carefully designed. Where does it say anything about setting up the 2x2 train token on the map of "The Place That Lies Beyond" (the second page of the "Big Girl Bed" story)? When reading through the story book as we were playing, this really threw me off, to the point of interrupting game play for way too long. Is that an omission in the game, and if so, should I expect more such sloppyness as the game progresses? Or did I miss a rule? Where would one place the train token, to the right or the left of the train track? Or should I simply stop being so picky and wing things dungeon-master-style as the game goes on?

Comment: [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1943150/article/28312014#28312014) says "The book tells you to put the train on the bottom right hand space on the tracks."  But without a copy of the rules I hesitate to put this as an answer especially as it doesn't say where this is written.